# advantages of using make and Cmake instead of compiling from the commandline?

Tags: cmake, gnu-make

I've always compiled all my C++ code under G++ from the commandline.

Why do people use things like Cmake and gcc make, and what are the advantages?

How can I convert my projects to using makefiles, if there really is a reason to?

Right now, I just use a text file with the list of all the commands I need to compile the project in pieces, and of course the one that compiles the entire project should I feel I want to recompile every c and cpp file.

Comment: In a large project it is an advantage to automatically recompile only those files that are affected by recent changes. Recompile all might take a while if you have thousands of source files.

Comment: Yeah but g++ lets you only recompile one or 2 or 3 c/cpp files. just use -c

Comment: You don't always know which `.cpp` files are impacted by your changes to header files. That's why we have depenency tracking tools.

Comment: Thank you very much, all of you! Should I make an answer to my own question citing what people commented, or simply mark the #1 reply as the answer (for future generations)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just use a text file with the list of all the commands I need to compile the project...

That's not a portable, standardized solution, it's unique to your personal workflow. A `Makefile` or `CMakefile` allows you to describe how to compile your code to *computers*, not to humans, so other people can run a simple command or two and (hopefully) get the same results as you.

Your approach might work now, but on a non-trivial project with thousands of source files, hundreds of thousands of intricate cross-dependencies, and takes hours to compile, you'll need automation.

For example, your text file might have:

```
 g++ input.cpp output -lstdc++
```

That's the most trivial case, one source file, one output file, one library. In non-trivial code the commands look like this:

```
g++ -m32 -c -g -Wall -Iinclude -Isrc -I../Perlingo\ Shared\ Objects -include include -fPIC  -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/src/BhamEvent.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/src/BhamEvent.o src/BhamEvent.cpp
```

That's just a taste for how many flags and options you might need to include to compile something properly. Some of those paths are variables stored in the `Makefile` or are put in there by a tool like `cmake` or `configure`.

Also one of the best things about a `Makefile` is you can do parallel builds with flags like `-j8` that builds up to eight things concurrently.

Comment: I thought the compiler told the computer how to compile my code

Comment: The compiler can only do what it's told and often compiling a file requires including a whole bunch of flags that aren't always obvious. A `Makefile` is like a batch file, but it's also a bit smarter: It won't build things that are already built unless their dependencies have changed.

Comment: so basically makefiles automate g++ -c calls?     Also, how exactly is passing the commandline args in a file with the project not portable? would you need different args based on the system? Wouldn't that be a bad design?

Comment: Telling people "here's how you compile my code" as a series of text-based instructions is really annoying because everyone knows tools like `make` and `cmake` exist which solve this problem. What I mean by "not portable" is those instructions might work on your machine, but other machines need different compiler flags or options. This is why tools like `configure` exist to test which compiler you're using, which libraries you hace, and set up things properly.

Comment: If you want to know why automation tools exist try building a big open-source project. Good examples include the [Linux kernel](https://www.kernel.org), [Chrome](https://github.com/chromium/chromium), or [Unreal Engine](https://github.com/EpicGames/UnrealEngine).

Comment: Thanks. uuh what should I do in terms of marking my question answered?

Comment: You've got two options on Stack Overflow: Upvotes for helpful answers, green check mark for "accepted" answer. The check-mark might not show up right away to give others a chance to try and answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of a **text file with the list of all the commands I need to compile the project** is one step on the way to an managed build.

Let us define the following levels of build improvement:

1. Compile every single file every time, dependencies are unknown
2. Cluster files to blocks or libs to build only in case it is necessary
3. Create a build description file and use `make` or `nmake`
4. Use a cross platform build description file and `cmake`
5. Use an IDE which can create your project based on the cmake file

I use level 1 for simple demonstrations of issues and solutions. But in my projects I work on level 5 always. And it seems your are on the transition from level 2 to level 3.

Comment: Codeblocks gives me weird compilation results (As in, it compiles but some functionalities of the software I wrote are... missing... like I can use some keys but not all of them with GLFW... but the rest of GLFW works absolutely fine!) and of course I would be caught dead before I use MSVC

Comment: Sorry, but in your question you wrote nothing about code::blocks or any other IDE. This is a Q&A website an not a discussion forum. I don't know why you wrote anything about MSVC if you are on linux. But I assume you don't know/like/consider/... any other IDE's. But you can ask for that.